# Como hacer una tabla de datos con GridView Android

Tags: android

Buenas tardes muchchachos quisiera saber la forma de manejar un GridView en Android para listar informacion como una tabla HTML, soy nuevo en esto y me sería muy util vuestra ayuda, gracias por la colaboracion

Comment: Probablemente el `GridView` no es ideal para crear algo como una tabla html. Revisaste el [`TableLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)?

Comment: con TableLayout he podido realizarlo, pero he escuchado varios comentarios que indican que este componente no es el más optimo, que el mejor es el GridView, entre otras cosas con el TableLayout No puedo dar estilos a las filas el aspecto es bastante plano. espero me puedas aconsejar amigo, gracias

Comment: Te sirve una tabla en que todas las columnas tienen el mismo ancho?

Comment: No, todos los campos son de diferente tamaño

Comment: Entonces no confía demasiado en todos comentarios que escuchas. `GridView` no te sirve, porque sus columnas todos tienen el mismo ancho, si no lo extendes y cambias el mètodo `layoutChildren()` (no documentado). Incluso un `LinearLayout` con una vista propia como fila sería más fácil de implementar.